# discord.py как получить количество пользователе онлайн на сервере

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

я пытался сделать используя on_member_update но так и не понял как

Answer (score 0):

```
sum([0 if member.status == discord.status.offline else 1 for member in after.guild.members])
```

Comment: ну наверняка есть в доках метод